# Add to Calendar button in PHP email

Tags: php, outlook, calendar

I have a form that people can fill out that allow them to select a date and time for an event. The form submits an email with all the form information.

I am trying to add a button in the email that's received to add the event to an Outlook calendar. I am able to make it work with Google, but not Outlook.

The email is being submitted via custom PHP. I tried AddToCalendar, but it won't work because email won't accept the JS that you need to run AddToCalendar. Even if there's a way to make the button download a custom .ics file, that's ok.

Any ideas or help with this is greatly appreciated. I can post any code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

"Add to Calendar" buttons can't be added to emails because emails can't execute Javascript. Therefore you should use "Add to Calendar" links instead.

At AddEvent.com we offer a simple "Events" tool which allows you to generate an event, copy the "Add to Calendar" links and paste them into your email/newsletter. The tool can be found here: https://www.addevent.com/events

What you alternatively can do is to create an event using a client/program like Outlook, save the event as a .ics file and attach it to your email. Most calendar vendors will detect the .ics file and offer an "Add to Calendar" link - at least Gmail does that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried using AddEvent.com, but, like you said, I can't use it because it requires JavaScript.the reason it needs to be in PHP/email, is because i am sending an email to multiple people, and they should have the option of adding the event to their calendar.

Comment: I completely missed out that you left a response, sorry about that Mike. The events tool I referred to isn't using Javascript but just plain text links to add events to a users calendar. The links approach in the tool works. Have a great Friday!